# How to hide pivot table when eager loading in Many To Many (Polymorphic) relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm building query to load modules in Many To Many (Polymorphic) relation with another model; and this query will be used in `Laravel-Excel` to export excel file.

The excel file generated successfully but with pivot table query, how can I hide the pivot table from the query?

Please advice,

Comment: unload the relation or if the instance of the model is converted to array at some point, you can add `pivot` to the hidden fields. It all depends on how you developed the your export class. Add your export class at least so we can help.

Comment: Show your code here
 or
You can use raw query or join yourself.